# method to combine multiple query result(node-postgres) in nodejs express.js response.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I followed a tutorial to send query results obtained from `pg` to response.json in node.js and express.js . code given below

```js
const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
```

but I am not to find any tutorial to send multiple query results something like below.

```js
const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results1) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    })
  }).then(  pool.query('SELECT * FROM provider ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results2) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json({"query1":results1.rows, "query2":results2.rows} )
  }
})
```

Comment: Here's the "callback hell" version: https://pastebin.com/b7KFXqFv

Comment: And here's the 2022 version: https://pastebin.com/7MtwQiYH

Comment: Is there any version requirement. or it is valid for express greater than 4.0

Comment: The relevant changes do not concern express. As long as `pool.query` returns a promise, the 2nd version should work fine.